# UISearchDisplayController searchResultsTableView not in a popover for the iPad?

Tags: iphone

In Apple's example code of TableSearch, on the iPad, when they search in their searchBar, the tableView gets updated to reflect what is being searched.  On the iPad, my SearchDisplayController puts the tableView in a UIPopoverController.  Is there any way to not have this behavior and update the list in the original tableView that takes up my whole screen instead?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I could get the desired functionality by not using the search display controller and just using the search bar's delegate method:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

     // filter content and reload table.
}
```